# Subcollections or Collections with Id / Reference in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app to record workouts (running). I previously used a local SQLite database to store all kinds of data (activities, activity profiles, settings and so on). I also wanted to have some sort on synchronisation with a remote server (for backup) but I didn't really want to implement this myself. So I recently found out about Google Firestore and it seems like it is exactly what I was looking for.

I have the following data model in my app (the User is the root class and below are some private fields that are all stored in separate tables in the SQLite database):

User

- List profiles - every profile contains information like total distance, used shoes, different heartrate zones.
- List activities - an Activity contains general information like distance travelled, elevation gain, a name and a list of DataRecord instances which contain geo-location information, heartrate and so on.

I think the Firestore API is pretty easy to understand, but right now I really don't know how to design my collections.
Right now, I only have a *users* collection.

Should I create a collection "activities" which holds a subcollection of DataRecords and a reference or the user id or should I only use the *users* collection and do everything with sub-collections? Is there any preference in regards to performance?

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any info about this? I am using both approaches in different projects and both work well, but I think I find that writing security rules for subcollections is usually easier

Comment: I didn't find anything about that, but I decided against using subcollections.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with sub-collections is that even if you delete the document containing the sub-collection, the sub-collection doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @inexcitus I'm having the same dilemma. Could you please outline the reasons why you decided against subcollections?

Comment: @MinasMina My comment is a little bit older, but in the current version I am in fact using subcollections. Why? Because in my personal opinion, I think it is a little bit more elegant because the data is "grouped". Right now, I use the following scheme: /<table name>/{user id}/data/<subcollection for documents>

Comment: Can no one list some pros and cons for references vs subcollections?

Comment: I found this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239419/firestore-datamodelling-articles-and-categories

It's a different issue but it might be useful for some.